# Change fields depending on drop down selection in Microsoft Word design mode

Tags: ms-word

Can anyone point me to info about how to create a Microsoft Word document that changes text input fields depending on what the user selects in a drop-down menu?

I'm using Word, Developer toolbar, Design mode, and have gotten as far as how to create the drop down selection box, and add text input fields below that on the page, but I need to know how to change what fields appear depending on what the selection is. I'm sure it's possible, I just don't know how to go about it.

I'm pretty good with this sort of thing in HTML with javascript and jQuery, but Word is its own little world.

I tried the "structured" tab but it suggests selecting XML add ins, and none appear in the list to select.

Answer (score 0):

One option is using a template approach in combination with 3rd party toolkit and external application. External application takes care for user interface where user selects template and sets filter for data retrieval. The application then reads the data, generates new document based on template and populates it with data.

You don’t have to mess with MS Word macros and this solution can survive Office upgrades very smoothly.

Template design in done in MS Word. We are using third party toolkit (i.e. [Docentric Toolkit](http://www.docentric.com/)) for populating Word documents with data.